# Non-trivial reshape in chunks

Tags: matlab, reshape

I am trying to reshape a matrix, but not in the standard way. It is basically a "chunk" reshape. I have a column vector named `matrix1` which is `(T*N x 1)` and a matrix named `matrix2` which is `TxN`. I want the first N elements of the column vector `matrix1` to be transposed into the first row of `matrix2`. Then the second chunk of N elements of vector `matrix1` to be transposed into the second row of `matrix2`.

I know how to do it with a loop (see code below). Just wondering if there is a smarter way to do it.

```
T = 2;
N = 7;

matrix1 = rand(T*N,1);
matrix2 = NaN(T,N);

for t = 1:T
    matrix2(t,:) = matrix1(t*N-N+1:t*N,1)';
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `reshape` for reshaping... You literally describe a standard reshape in the text.

```
reshape(matrix1,N,T).'
```